# How can I override compareTo method in a class I wrote to compare Strings stored in the class?

Tags: java, string, comparable, compareto

I wrote a class, MyClass, and each instance has a String "name" field. I want to override the compareTo method so that when called it will compare the two "name" fields of each instance.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass>{

    public String name;
    public int age;

    public MyClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = 0;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyClass mc) {
        return this.name.compareTo(mc.name);
    }

}
```

When I go to add instances of this class into an ordered list container I wrote, they are not added in the order I want, which is alphabetically. The ordered list doesn't seem to be the problem, as I tested it by adding Strings which are added in the correct order.

Here is the add() method of the ordered list:

```
public boolean add(E obj) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node(obj);
    Node<E> current = head, previous = null;
    if (current == null) { // EMPTY list
        head = tail = newNode;
        currentSize++;
        modCounter++;
        return true;
    }
    while (current != null
            && ((Comparable<E>) obj).compareTo(current.data) > 0) {
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
    if (previous == null) {         // One item in list, inserted node must go in FIRST position
        newNode.next = current;
        head = newNode;
    } else if (current == null) {   // Inserted node must go at the END of the list
        previous.next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    } else {                        // Inserted node is somewhere in the MIDDLE of the list
        newNode.next = current;
        previous.next = newNode;
    }
    currentSize++;
    modCounter++;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @vtheron "an ordered list container **i wrote**" seems he wrote it to me. Regardless, he's talking about ordering strings alphabetically and you can see in his code he's comparing them in whatever case they're in when the comparison should be caseless.

Comment: Yes, I am writing the ordered list container class using an ordered linked list. I just updated the question with the add() method from the ordered list class, as requested by @JAMM

Answer (score 0):

You've already answered your question, however one thing you have to know about alphabetizing strings is that case matters. If you're strictly comparing without the care for case then you should either upcase or downcase both strings:

```
return this.name.toLowerCase().compareTo(mc.name.toLowerCase());
```

Otherwise `"Bravo"` comes before `"alpha"` due to case.

Comment: yes, looks like I did answer my own question, I was making changes to a copy of the MyClass file, and not the one I was testing. For this project, case does not matter, but I will remember your advice in the future! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to add it to a Tree... so u order it while adding

```
import java.util.TreeSet;


TreeSet tree = new TreeSet();
tree.add(instanceOfMyClass);
```

since u added the comparable interface the tree set knows how to handle it

if this works it seems that u are still comparing the strings in your ordered list, and u should now check if the return value of compareTo is less/grater/equal to 0;

Comment: He's using his own collection that should be sorting them on entry so the need to use a different collection to perform the task isn't much of an answer.

Comment: @JAMM As much as I'd like to implement a tree from java.util, the project I'm working on requires me to write an ordered list data structure. Thanks for the response

Comment: could you post the part with the compare function of the add function of your ordered list? and an example of how u create/add the instances of MyClass